# how to get current User's information from realtime database firebase using react native

Tags: database, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

```js
firebase
    .database().
    ref('UsersList/' + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    .once('value').then(snapshot => {
        console.log(snapshot.val())
    });
```

that's my code which I am using in componentDidMount() function on the home page after signing up a user.

Comment: what does the code return?

Answer (score 0):

Set an authentication state observer and get user data :

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
    var displayName = user.displayName;
    var email = user.email;
    var emailVerified = user.emailVerified;
    var photoURL = user.photoURL;
    var isAnonymous = user.isAnonymous;
    var uid = user.uid;
    var providerData = user.providerData;
    // ...
  } else {
    // User is signed out.
    // ...
  }
});
```